# Python - Problem using height and labeling variables at plot

Tags: python, seaborn, data-analysis

I am trying to resolve an exercise for Exploratory Data Analysis in Python with a Kaggle dataset
Here's my code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import stat
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
sns.set(style = "white")

clean_data_path = "dataset/autos.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(clean_data_path,encoding = "latin-1")

a = sns.countplot(x='vehicleType',data=df, height= 6,aspect= 1.5)
a.axes.set_title('Contagem de total de veículos à venda de carros por tipo de veículo',fontsize=15)
a.set_xlabel('Tipo de Veículo',fontsize=15)
a.set_ylabel('Total de Veículos para Venda',fontsize=15)
for p in a.ax.patches:
    a.ax.annotate((p.get_height()), (p.get_x()+0.1, p.get_height()+500))
```

With this code i'm getting TypeError: bar() got multiple values for argument 'height', while with the answer code:

```
g = sns.catplot(x="vehicleType", data=df, kind="count", palette="BuPu", height=6, aspect=1.5)
g.ax.xaxis.set_label_text("Tipo de Veículo",fontdict= {'size':16})
g.ax.yaxis.set_label_text("Total de Veículos Para Venda", fontdict= {'size':16})
g.ax.set_title("Contagem total de veículos à venda conforme o tipo de veículo",fontdict= {'size':18})
for p in g.ax.patches:
    g.ax.annotate((p.get_height()), (p.get_x()+0.1, p.get_height()+500))
```

Everything runs smoothly, can anyone answer me why? thanks

Comment: In `sns.catplot`, `height=` is silently ignored. In `sns.countplot` the height is passed to `plt.barplot` where it causes confusion, as the bar height is already defined by the counts. Just leave out `height=` on both.

Comment: I see, so in countplot height is not and attribute, but how do I get to put the numbers labels on top of the bars in a countplot?

Comment: Maybe your problem is caused by adding the value 500? It could be better to use a newline as in  `ax.annotate(f'{(p.get_height()}\n'), (p.get_x()+0.1, p.get_height()))`. As `countplot` returns an ax, it's easier to write `ax = sns.countplot(...)` and `for p in ax.patches:`.